# Flutter medical image/file view DICOM File and doc,docx,pdf view/open in flutter app

Tags: android, ios, flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am new to flutter there is an requirement for me to view
medical image (DICOM file /image) how to view/open in my flutter app and

View PDF and doc,docx (especially) in android and ios application without using or opening any other document viewer apps. I need to show PDF and doc,docx file in my app not in third party apps.
I use some dart package but not working like file_open, file_picker, file_reader only works pdf_viewer for pdf file but other extension not working please give any solutions

Thank you.

Comment: @Navanath Did you find a solution to this?

Comment: @Umair seems like he found the answer on [reddit](https://www.reddit.com/r/flutterhelp/comments/mudp1g/flutter_medical_imagefile_view_dicom_file_and/)